# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else, completely stumped

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

```
if (monthsResult2 === 1) {
    monthsAppend = "month";
} else if (monthsResult2 > 1)
    monthsAppend = "months";
} else {
    monthsAppend = " ";           
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue with the if/else statement is? I am currently getting the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

But after looking at multiple examples I can't for the life of me see what I am doing wrong! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Missing opening bracket at the end of the 3rd line.

Comment: An error which the Allman indention style, the only correct style, could spare you from. http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2009/04/10/the-only-correct-indent-style/

Comment: @pcr322 Or a syntax highlighter.

Comment: @prc322 Javascript is the only exception to this rule. K&R is best for Javascript. Complete infos about why : https://youtu.be/hQVTIJBZook?t=30m47s It's not easiely readable, but it prevents "bugs".

Comment: @Heru-Luin: Weak argument. Just another quirk of JS. You can avoid this and still stick to Allman. Which gives you damn fine JS. Proof: https://github.com/prc322?tab=repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget the open of the curly brace `{` in your `else if`.

```
else if (monthsResult2 > 1) 
                            ^
}
```

Try this:

```
if (monthsResult2 === 1) {
    monthsAppend = "month";
} else if (monthsResult2 > 1) {
    monthsAppend = "months";
} else {
    monthsAppend = " ";           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya forgot a `{` in your `else if`

```
if (monthsResult2 === 1) {
    monthsAppend = "month";
} else if (monthsResult2 > 1) {
    monthsAppend = "months";
} else {
    monthsAppend = " ";
}
```